# Cannot change background-color for mat-card from style.scss

Tags: angular, angular-material, background-color, mat-card

I would like to change the `background-color` for the `mat-card` inside the `style.scss` for my angular project.

The `AppComponent` is the only component I am using currently. 
It is possible the change the `width` for the `mat-card`, but I am not able to change the `background-color` from the `style.scss` file.

Changing the `background-color` in the `app.component.scss` works.
Also I am able to change the style for example a `<p></p>` element from the `style.scss`.

Why does the `background-color` not change, but the `p` element does?

Comment: can you add stackbliz example of your problem or atleast add some code here

Comment: How did you write your style in style.scss?

Comment: I don't see any problem changing color from style.css  

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uy8r3c

Comment: I used the `mat-card` selector directly and not a css class

Comment: It has to do with [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). `mat-card` already has a background color so you have to override the existing one with a css selector with higher specificity.